Choosing between additive and multiplicative survival model
I am performing a research on timing of housing construction using survival model. The issue I have now is to choose between additive and multiplicative survival models. What should I consider when choosing between the two, and is there any test statistics that can help with this decision?

The best place to start would be with related work in your field, determining what has worked best for others in similar studies. The "multiplicative" versus "additive" distinction in time-series analysis isn't typically used in survival analysis, at least in the clinical applications with which I'm familiar.
The focus in survival models is generally on the hazard function, the instantaneous risk of an event. There are 3 general ways to model the hazard as a function of covariates and time.
Two might be considered "multiplicative" as they are based on additive models after log transformations. One is the proportional hazards (PH) approach, in which the log-hazard is a linear function of predictors. A second is the accelerated failure time approach, in which the distribution of the logs of event times is a linear function of predictors. In the R survival package those are typically fit by the coxph() and survreg() functions, respectively.
A third general approach is "additive," modeling the hazard itself over time as a linear function of predictors (with potentially time-varying coefficients). The aareg() function of the survival package can fit such models, but it doesn't seem to be used very often.
If there aren't strong theoretical reasons supporting an alternative, one approach is to start with a Cox PH model, taking advantage of its lack of assumptions about baseline hazard. Then use information about the nature of any lack of fit to adapt the Cox model or to guide other choices. This draws from Chapter 6 of "Modeling Survival Data: Extending the Cox Model" by Therneau and Grambsch. Chapter 6 discusses how to test the PH assumption and what to do when it fails.
In Section 6.6 they make the critical point that apparent violations of PH can arise from a mis-specified model rather than true PH failure. For example, omitting an outcome-associated predictor or choosing the wrong functional form for a continuous predictor can masquerade as a PH violation. Check those possibilities first!
If PH is still violated, a plot of the scaled Schoenfeld residuals over time can suggest the functional form of a time-varying coefficient for a predictor that might match the data better. The time-dependence vignette of the R survival package goes into detail.
In that Section, Therneau and Grambsch note (p. 149): "when the coefficient effects are not too big, either of [AFT or additive models] may be approximated by a time-varying coefficient Cox model." That gives you the choice of continuing with the Cox model with time-varying coefficients or using the nature of the time-varying coefficient to help make another choice.
For example, for the Aalen additive model with baseline hazard $\lambda_0(t)$, you can write the hazard as a function of time and covariates $X$ having time-varying coefficients $\beta(t)$ as:
$$ \lambda(t) = \lambda_0(t)[1 + \beta(t)X/\lambda_0(t)].$$
You can then take advantage of $\log(1+x) \approx x$ for small $x$ to put the additive model approximately into the form of a Cox model with time-varying coefficient(s):
$$ \lambda(t) \approx \lambda_0(t) e^{\beta(t)X/\lambda_0(t)}.$$
For an AFT model, a similar approximation leads to "the form of a time-varying coefficient Cox model where there is a common time modulation for all covariates."
These insights have two implications. First, the form of a PH violation in a Cox model can provide information about whether an AFT or additive model might be preferable. Second, if covariate associations with outcome aren't too large, the distinctions among the 3 types of models also might not be too large if you are willing to work with time-varying coefficients in a Cox model. Whether the hazards are "truly" multiplicative or additive in some sense might not matter in practice.
Whichever type of model you choose, I'd recommend reading Chapters 17 to 21 of Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies on survival analysis. It's particularly helpful on ways to evaluate goodness of fit of different types of models and how to use re-sampling to validate and calibrate the modeling process.

Thank you for your answer! I am well aware of these models. I just wanted to see if there is a procedure that helps with the decision. For instance there is tests and methods to find whether to use AFT or proportional hazard. but verifying the hazard is actually additive or multiplicative is my main issue. For now my data shows properties that require additive hazard model (time varying coefficients).

@BabakFiFoo I've extended the answer to include one potentially useful approach: start with a Cox model, then (if it doesn't work adequately) use information about how it fails to fit to point to a different model type.
